# Which 'Fkey' can I safely use in a cross-platform application?

Tags: keys, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm developing a text editor and start to think about key bindings.

Which F key (F1, F2, F11, etc.) should I use in my application, assuming that I want OS X users to be able to use it as well? I don't want to bind keys that are already used in Windows, Mac OS or Linux common distributions.

Comment: There will be ways for users to change the key bindings, right?

Comment: @FrustatedWithFormsDesigner I think that yes, I'll give the user this possibility, but the aim is to make it the most minimal possible - so I need strong and simple default key bindings to avoid losing the user at first glance.

Comment: There's an informal list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_key).  Obviously, all of the non-shifted keys are already spoken for, so you might have better luck with the Shift-Fn keys and Alt-Fn keys.

Comment: You should also consider using a set of keys that text editor users are already familiar with, like [this one](https://www.howtogeek.com/115664/42-text-editing-keyboard-shortcuts-that-work-almost-everywhere/).

Comment: Your comments could have been an answer ! Thank you very much @Robert Harvey. Don't ask me why but I didn't think of Wikipedia for the list of function keys... And thanks for the second link as wellw it may be prettu useful :)